# Render large DOM content from variable to page without freezing page

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I developed an application which takes html file from user, modify it and display its content using html5 file API. When I am going to render it, its freezing for small amount of time, the time is depending on the size of file, If the filesize is 1M then it is taking 5-6 sec. Is there any way to load DOM content asynchronously without freezing page?

Comment: Probably Web Workers, unless the blocking is due to actual re-reading of DOM by client, in which case it may not be something you can get around. How are you going from parsing the file to outputting to DOM? Are you creating the elements and then appending when the full node is built, or are you appending as you go?

Comment: I am using jquery's text() method to display html file content.